# Using a file as a USB device in VirtualBox

Tags: linux, virtualbox

I'm aware that, in Linux, a loop device is a pseudo-device that makes a computer file accessible as a block device. I need something very similar (or the same thing?) to use a file as a VirtualBox USB device.

I have a Linux host and a Linux guest. My goal is to test, inside a virtual machine, tools like Easy2Boot, UNetbootin, Ventoy, and the similar.

The simplest case is to connect a real USB device to the host machine and use it as a USB device in the guest machine. It would certainly work.

My problem, however, is that since I have to do dozens of tests with a slow real USB, I would prefer to do the same tests with a fast fake USB.

The fast fake USB would be nothing more than a file in my computer's internal SSD drive. On this fast SSD disk, the virtual machine is also located.

Comment: To test a real hardware device, I think your fake USB (file) would have to emulate hardware USB. I otherwise do not see how this might work.

Comment: Where you configure storage devices, you can create a virtual USB controller (aside/instead of more common IDE) and attach a file-based "hard disk". Is this what you want?

Comment: E2B, Ventoy, etc. should work exactly the same whether they boot from a USB drive or a SATA or IDE hard disk. So just create a VHD or VDI with whatever contents you like and attach it to the VM plus whatever (new) VHD\VDI for the OS you are going to install (most PCs have at least one internal HDD). The only issues are 1) in legacy mode the USB drive will be enumerated by an *OS* as disk 0 whereas on  a real system hd0 would be the internal HDD, 2) an OS will 'see' the USB VDI\VHD as a hard disk and not a USB drive - the drive will not be seen as a 'Removable' drive.

Comment: @SSi The question is not totally clear about it, but I think the problem is not with booting a tool. It's about giving the tool an emulated USB to work with later.

Comment: I thank all of you for your comments. What I asked is not possible with Virtualbox. However, I have added an answer that solves my problem with QEMU.

Comment: This should actually be possible with VirtualBox, using a virtual USB storage controller (this is not physical hardware that is emulated but due to the VirtualBox settings structure). However, I doubt the VirtualBox firmware supports USB booting.

Comment: @DanielB Yes, it is how you wrote. We can add a virtual USB controller in VirtualBox settings and a VDI disk that appears as a USB stick inside the guest. Still, it is impossible to boot from it. So, in conclusion, the solution I found in QEMU is not replicable in VirtualBox. Also, there is a bug because adding a virtual USB controller causes an NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005) in VirtualBox 6.1.36.

Comment: Just a note: this has been asked many times. Google this so the list: _virtualbox virtual usb key site:superuser.com_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The answer is that, with VirtualBox, it is not possible,** as specified in the comment [Using a file as a USB device in VirtualBox](https://superuser.com/questions/1744652/using-a-file-as-a-usb-device-in-virtualbox?noredirect=1#comment2706532_1744652).  **It is, however, possible with other hypervisors, such as QEMU.**

In this specific case, after creating a `qcow2` virtual disk with `virt-manager` and installing a Linux system of my choice on it (e.g., Linux Mint 21), I can make a file containing the fake USB device with:

`fallocate -l 8G ./rawUsbDisk.img`

I can create a folder on the host machine and share it with Samba so that it is accessible to the guest machine (I need to put ISO files there for testing). SAMBA sharing in QEMU is explained at https://techpiezo.com/linux/shared-folder-in-qemu-virtual-machine-linux/.

After that, I can move the `qcow2` file to the home folder to use it with QEMU instead of `virt-manager`.

This is the command that answers my question:

```
/usr/bin/qemu-system-x86_64 -hda LinuxMint21.qcow2 -m 4096 -enable-kvm \
    -smp 2                                                             \
    -cpu host                                                          \
    -net nic -net user,smb=/home/francesco/Condivisione                \
    -device virtio-gpu-pci                                             \
    -drive if=none,id=usbstick,format=raw,file=./rawUsbDisk.img        \
    -usb                                                               \
    -device usb-ehci,id=ehci                                           \
    -device usb-tablet,bus=usb-bus.0                                   \
    -device usb-storage,bus=ehci.0,drive=usbstick                      \
    -boot menu=on
```

The `-boot menu=on` option allows me, when starting the virtual machine, to choose whether to boot from the virtual hard disk or the fake USB device:

[image]

The following options are for fake USB and are explained in https://qemu.readthedocs.io/en/latest/system/devices/usb.html:

```
    -drive if=none,id=usbstick,format=raw,file=./rawUsbDisk.img        \
    -usb                                                               \
    -device usb-ehci,id=ehci                                           \
    -device usb-tablet,bus=usb-bus.0                                   \
    -device usb-storage,bus=ehci.0,drive=usbstick
```

This way, inside the virtual machine, Gparted sees `/dev/sdb` as a USB disk:

[image]

After creating an msdos partition table and a single FAT32 partition, the virtual machine correctly recognizes the fake usb stick:

[image]

I am ready to do as many tests as I wish with Unetbootin and similar tools:

[image]

After running Unetbootin or other similar tool, I can restart the virtual machine and boot from USB:

[image]

The result is that I can run a test in a few minutes instead of half an hour or more because of the slowness of my hardware USB.